# How to create a bytes or bytearray of given length filled with zeros in Python?

Tags: python, arrays

All the solutions I found were for lists.

Thanks.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

This will give you 100 zero bytes:

```
bytearray(100)
```

Or filling the array with non zero values:

```
bytearray([1] * 100)
```

Comment: How about filling the array with certain value, different than zero?

Answer (score 25):

For `bytes`, one may also use the literal form `b'\0' * 100`.

```
# Python 3.6.4 (64-bit), Windows 10
from timeit import timeit
print(timeit(r'b"\0" * 100'))  # 0.04987576772443264
print(timeit('bytes(100)'))  # 0.1353608166305015
```

**Update1:** With [constant folding in Python 3.7](https://bugs.python.org/issue29469), the literal from is now almost 20 times faster.

**Update2:**
Apparently constant folding has a limit:

```
>>> from dis import dis
>>> dis(r'b"\0" * 4096')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (b'\x00\x00\x00...')
              2 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis(r'b"\0" * 4097')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (b'\x00')
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (4097)
              4 BINARY_MULTIPLY
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Am I misunderstanding how timeit works? When I type the following: >>> r'b"\0" * 100" python returns: 'b"\\0" * 100'     So, is this example really timing the creation of 100 elements? If I type in print(timeit("b'0x00' * 100")) I get a significantly longer time.

Comment: @e-holder `timeit` passes the string statement to `compile` and then `exec`. Why would wrapping `timeit` in a `print` function have a significant effect on the timer output? It's just printing a float *after* the timing is finished. I cannot reproduce.

Comment: My confusion is whether the leading 'r' is causing the expression to be merely the definition of a string versus an expression to generate a 100 element array. If I enter the expression >>> b = r'b"\0" * 100'  >>> b   All I get is a string as the value of b. But if I enter the expression >>> b = b"\0" * 100  >>> b   I get a 100 element array as the value of b. Do you see why I am confused?

Comment: Okay. I am wrong. print(timeit(r'b"\0" * 100000') takes significantly longer, so it isn't just building a string.

Comment: @AXO Could you please clarify whether this performance speedup also applies if the size is not actually a constant?

Comment: @TomášZato Testing on Python 3.11, `b'\0' * int_var` is almost 1.76 times faster than `bytearray(int_var)` where `int_var = 100`, but of course this is not as dramatic as the constant folding speedup and also slower than using an integer literal.

Comment: @AXO This bring up the question of which type is *dynamically* allocated vs. a *pre-allocated* array being filled? Any insight?

Comment: @not2qubit Interesting, but sorry, I don't know. My guess is that if the final size is somehow known to the interpreter before it starts to create the object, then it will try to use it to preallocate (like how it does for [`[None] * integer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22225666/pre-allocating-a-list-of-none)).